# Matlab class function - getting returned value

Tags: class, matlab, methods

In my project I use two classes - row and triangle. Class row in its functions creates triangle class objects:

```
classdef row < handle

% some parameters here

methods

% constructor and some other functions here

function [T1 T2] = createFoR(obj, hT, Alpha, Beta, DeltaAlpha, DeltaBeta)
         % creating P1 matrix (irrelevant, its 100% correct)
         T1 = triangle(P1);
         % creating P2 matrix (irrelevant, its 100% correct)
         T2 = triangle(P2);
end

end
```

When I'm calling this row class function like this:

```
[T1 T2] = Row1.createFoR(T(1,1), Alpha, Beta, DeltaAlpha, DeltaBeta);
```

or like this:

```
[T(2,1) T2] = Row1.createFoR(T(1,1), Alpha, Beta, DeltaAlpha, DeltaBeta);
```

everything works perfectly fine. But when I attempt to assign both returned triangle objects to array cells like this:

```
[T(2,1) T(2,2)] = Row1.createFoR(T(1,1), Alpha, Beta, DeltaAlpha, DeltaBeta);
```

I get this error:

```
Error using triangle (line 10)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in test (line 20)
[T(2,1) T(2,2)] = Row1.createFoR(T(1,1), Alpha, Beta, DeltaAlpha, DeltaBeta);
```

May I kindly ask you to explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think data types would help here.  Is T a 2x2 matrix while triangle returns a double?

Comment: T is 2x2 matrix which contains triangle objects. triangle function is a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>It looks like T is an object, where T(double,double) is a function/constructor.  So in the case you point out</s>

```
[T(2,1) T(2,2)] = Row1.createFoR(T(1,1), Alpha, Beta, DeltaAlpha, DeltaBeta);
```

<s>You are actually calling T(double, double) three times, where the error occurs specifically in T(2,2), (where the code is 100% correct?).</s>

**Updated from comment**

What is odd is the input argument error in triangle line 10.  Could the problem be in P1, P2?

You could also try the following - but its guesswork without something I can run/reproduce the problem (the error is in code not listed?)

```
[T1 T2] = Row1.createFoR(T(1,1), Alpha, Beta, DeltaAlpha, DeltaBeta);
T(2,1:2) = [T1, T2];
```

**Answer:**

Another thought is that when T(2,2) is filled its trying to construct T(1,2) with no arguments?

Comment: T is 2x2 array of triangle objects. T(int, int) is just a reference to arrays cell = concrete triangle object. (Filling P matrix which is argument of triangle constructor is correctly implemented)

Comment: Personally I have had better success using cells instead of matrices for objects {} vs [].

Comment: You were correct about creating T(1,2) object with no argument. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Glad I could help - took a little bit of guessing :-)